# how to return from async to normal execution in typescript

Tags: asynchronous, typescript, promise, return, async-await

in `TypeScript`, to resolve the promise, I use the `await` keyword.
but that keyword is only allowed to exist in the body of `async functions`, which return `Promise<T>`.
in that case, the function that calls this `async` function, will need to resolve the return value: `Promise<T>`, which means i'll again need the `await` keyword, and that function will have to be defined as async as well.

What am I missing?

Comment: I understand await as: wait until promise resolves (or errors), and unwrap the object to get the value.

Comment: In summary, you can't.  Once async, always async.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to `await`, you can use `then` on the promise.
Here's the scenario you've described:

```
async function fn(): Promise<number> {
    return new Promise<number>((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(resolve.bind(null, 2), 1500);
    });
}

async function fn2(num: number) {
    return await fn() * num;
}

function fn3(num: number) {
    fn2(num).then(num => {
        console.log(`returned number: ${num}`);
    })
}

fn3(10);
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=async%20function%20fn()%3A%20Promise%3Cnumber%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Promise%3Cnumber%3E((resolve%2C%20reject)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20setTimeout(resolve.bind(null%2C%202)%2C%201500)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aasync%20function%20fn2(num%3A%20number)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20await%20fn()%20*%20num%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20fn3(num%3A%20number)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn2(num).then(num%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%60returned%20number%3A%20%24%7Bnum%7D%60)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0A%7D%0A%0Afn3(10)%3B))

Which outputs this after `1500` milliseconds:

> returned number: 20

---

#### Edit

Doing this:

```
var x = fn2(3).then(num => { return num * 2 });
console.log(x);
```

Will log something like:

> Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}

To get the value you need to use then:

```
x.then(num => console.log(num));
```

You can not assign the result of an async operation into a variable without using `await`.

Comment: if I do `return` from `then` clause, is this the returned value, or stored in a variable inside the body?

`var x = fn2(num).then(num => {return num*2 }`

will this assign x or return?

Comment: check my revised answer